# How can I refresh the page after an ajax call but passing parameters as well? I.e. not full refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using ajax from JQuery. I am doing in a page that I see the results of a POST/GET having provided specific parameters as filters to the server.
Assume I have provided parameters a&b&c to the user so that I see in the page the subset of the data that these parameters hold true.
In a specific case I do an ajax call to pass a value to the server that modifies this set that I am seeing.
What I need is a way to do a refresh of the page but that will only display the new version of the current subset of data I.e. somehow refreshing passing back to the server a&b&c
Right now I am doing:  `window.location.reload(true);` which reloads **all** the data and it is time-consuming to re-apply the filters manually.
How can I solve this?
Essentially what I need is not full refresh?

Comment: Can you please show your code?...

Comment: I'm still a little lost as to why a refresh is needed?

Comment: @Neal:I do `$ajax({url etc.` and then `window.location.reload(true); `

Comment: @tymeJV:Because I do an update of the specific subset of the data I am seeing in the browser and I want to see the effect of the update on the subset and not 1)do a full refresh 2)apply filters to see that the update had effect

Comment: Why vote to close?Is this such a bad question?What kind of code do I need to put?

Comment: If you are using Ajax from jQuery and want to do a partial reload but have chosen window.location.reload, then you are doing it wrong. Just do a `$("#someDiv").load("someUrl?a=x&b=y")` or `$.get("someUrl?a=x&b=y",function(data) { $("#someDiv").html(data)});`

Comment: @mplungjan:Would it be possible to provide an answer clarifying this?I am new to JQuery and I am googling my way to code. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ajax from jQuery and want to do a partial reload but have chosen window.location.reload, then you are doing it wrong.

Use the format

```
$("#someDiv").load("someUrl?a=x&b=y")
```

or

```
$.get("someUrl?a=x&b=y",function(data) { $("#someDiv").html(data)});
```

for example this code in the head where .parameters could be checkboxes

```
$(function() {
  $(".parameters").on("click",function() { 
    var url = "someUrl.php?"+$("#myForm").serialize();
    $.get(url,function(data) {
      $("#someContainer").html(data);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: What is `somediv`?I don't understand this part

Comment: Use your imagination. someDiv is just some div with ID="someDiv" or whatever you want to call it - same for someContainer

Comment: I figured that.But which div to we choose? Any random one? Or does it need to be a div of a form?

Comment: Whatever you want. There is no such thing as a div of a form. You can also format the result into a UL or OL or something else

Comment: What is `data` in your example?I don't really want to repopulate "manually" the components by the result.I want it to be like a pseudo-refresh.Does this make sense?

Comment: Data is what is returned from the server!

Comment: But in my case originally I have a table. Can't I just fetch the page? This way I need to populate the html table myself?

Comment: Or return the table and have someDiv or someContainer wrap the table

Answer (score 0):

You would have to **return** something from the server which will contain th einformation needed to update

And then update the content based on the returned data.

Comment: I figured that but which api should I use?